# Need help in creating a windows batch file which will look for certain file types

Tags: batch-file

I haven't worked on a windows machines before, and i have a requirement to delete some files in a particular folder and once the files are cleared we should be zipping the files. is there any possible way.

I need to run the batch file, should be prompting me with the target path where i need to enter the values once done it should be deleting *.txt files in it and once deletion is complete it should zip the folder and send it to a new directory .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
rem Prompt for the target path
set /p TargetPath=Target path: 
rem Delete text files
del /q %TargetPath%\*.txt
rem Create zip archive
zip -r -j C:\SomeNewDirectory\foo.zip %TargetPath%
```

Adapt to your needs.

Comment: I would add a `if not exist %targetpath%\nul` command before proceeding to delete the files...

Comment: With a question like that which shows nearly no prior research effort my incentives of giving a good answer are not that high ... ;-)